# Prove that a $\alpha$ Holder function is also a $\beta$ Holder function.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact set.

Also, we have $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is $\alpha$ Holder. which means that there exists $0<\alpha \leq 1\;$ and $K>0\;$ such that $\left|f(x)-f(y)\right|\leq K\left\Vert x-y\right\Vert ^{\alpha}\;$ for all $x,y\in  X$

I want to show that for $0<\beta<\alpha \leq 1\;$, $f$ is also $\beta$ Holder.

I tried by proof by contradiction.

Assume that $f$ is not $\beta$ Holder, Therefore $\forall K'>0$ there exists $x_0,y_0\in X$ such that $ \left|f(x_{0})-f(y_{0})\right|>K'\left\Vert x_{0}-y_{0}\right\Vert ^{\beta}$.

Lets pick $K=K'$, and split into cases.

If $\left\Vert x_{0}-y_{0}\right\Vert \leq1$ then $\left\Vert x_{0}-y_{0}\right\Vert ^{\alpha}<\left\Vert x_{0}-y_{0}\right\Vert ^{\beta}$ and we get

$\left|f(x_{0})-f(y_{0})\right|>K\left\Vert x_{0}-y_{0}\right\Vert ^{\beta}>K\left\Vert x_{0}-y_{0}\right\Vert ^{\alpha}$ which contradicts that $f$ is $\alpha$ Holder.

However, I wasnt able to deal with the case where $\left\Vert x_{0}-y_{0}\right\Vert >1$

I would love to get some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contradiction will work, but you need to take $K' = K \sup_{x,y \in X} |x-y|^{\alpha - \beta}$ instead of just setting it equal to $K$. This is a finite constant since $K$ is compact and hence is bounded and $\alpha - \beta \geq 0$.

However, a simpler way of writing this is to avoid aiming for a contradiction altogether and just to note that for $x,y \in X$,
$$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq K |x-y|^\alpha = K |x-y|^{\alpha - \beta} |x-y|^\beta \leq \left (K \sup_{x,y \in X} |x-y|^{\alpha - \beta} \right) |x-y|^\beta.$$